# javascript : to fetch iframe element ,but it can not get the value

Tags: javascript

i try to fetch the frame head value ,but it doesn't work well,look at the following code

1.php

```
<iframe src="/admin/" ></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // var a = 
    a = window.top.frames[0].a
    alert(a)
</script>
```

/admin/index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = 'a=asdf';
    a = 'asdf'
</script>
```

---

Look the result

when i open http://127.0.0.1/1.php in firefox or chrome it become that followings

[open in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGfMi.png)

but when i execute it in the console it come into that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPX80.png)

so My question is Why my code can't get the value of Tag iframe

Comment: Please do not post images. Edit your question and post the code properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code under window load function or may be iframe load because iframe takes some time to load and you have to wait for it to be fully loadded.

```
<iframe src="/admin/" ></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    // var a = 
    a = window.top.frames[0].a
    alert(a)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks ,I get it. And solve it successfully, By following code.
setTimeout("a = window.top.frames[0].a;alert(a)", 3000 )